# using namespace issue

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-statement

When I use the following

```
#include <map>

using namespace LCDControl;
```

Any reference to the std namespace ends up being associated with the LCDControl name space.

For instance:

```
Generic.h:249: error: 'map' is not a member of 'LCDControl::std'
```

How do I get around this? I didn't see anything specific to this on any documentation I looked over. Most of them said not to use: using namespace std;.

Here's line 249:

```
for(std::map<std::string,Widget *>::iterator w = widgets_.begin();
```

Comment: What compiler? Also, do you have anything named `map` in your LCDControl namespace? Why use `using namespace` anyway? :)

Comment: GMan, no 'map is in the LCDControl namespace. I used a namespace because I kept running into names associated with outside header files. For instance, in this case I had something named CHAR, and it conflicted with something somewhere. Instead of renaming it, I dealt with it by wrapping everything inside a namespace. Of course I've never used C++ namespaces before, so here I am. :)

Comment: Do you use `std` as a class or namespace identifier anywhere?

Comment: @gf: Nope. Even if I did, I would have capitalized it.

Comment: That's strange, it's behaving as if you forgot to `include <map>`.  Does it work if you use `::std::map` instead of `std::map`?

Comment: What I mean was why use the `using` directive. Just prefix your classes with `LCDControl::`. In the same way `using namespace std` is discouraged, this might be. Also, if you had a conflict with CHAR, why not use the existing CHAR?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, it sure does work.

Comment: @Gman: Because my CHAR was a char *, and I have no idea what the existing CHAR was.

Comment: Hmm, seems as if something in `LCDControl` is hiding `std`.  Is there a `using namespace std` within the `namespace LCDControl { }` anywhere?

Comment: @Gman: One reason I don't want to use LCDControl:: on everything is because that would be a whole lot of editing to do. A lot.

Comment: One thing that might cause that is if one of the STL headers is being included somewhere within the LCDControl namespace.  e.g., `namespace LCDControl { #include <string> }`.

Comment: Hold on, I'm going to submit my comments as an answer...

Comment: Search and replace should accelerate that. You can also always alias it (`namespace lcd = LCDControl; lcd::foo();`). Saves typing and can improve readability.

Comment: @Tim: I may have wrapped an #include <map> somewhere inside namespace LCDControl {}; somewhere. It'll take some time to check everything.

Comment: CHAR was probably a `char`. Turning CHAR into a `char*` is confusing...but obviously up to you. Also, you can alias if you want: `namespace lcd = LCDControl`. But really, namespaces exist for a reason, and `using namespace` completely circumvents that.

Comment: @ gf, good thinking with the alias :P

Comment: GMan: Well, CHAR refers to a special character on the LCD. It's an unsigned char[8] -- 8 rows, 6  columns. CHAR was shorter than SPECIAL_CHAR. :)

Comment: Interesting... :) Sounds like a job for another class :) `namespace LCDControl { class character {...}; }`

Comment: @Gman: Oh, I already have a SpecialChar class. I have one single array of 6 special characters meant to be a placeholder till I write up an algorithm to generate them from code. It's for the bar widget. The bars can be split, meaning that each character cell can have a bottom and top have, indicating two different values. Also, the bar can be "hollow" meaning that there's a border around the entire bar. Sad thing is, there's only 8 characters total, so you can't have hollow and split at the same time. Lcd4linux uses a complicated algorithm to accomodate for this. It introduces limitations tho.

Comment: I'm very interested in what you're doing, now. :( Programming LCD's sound fun, I only did it once two years ago in my first assembly class.

Comment: Maybe you should submit the linker issue as a separate question.  I would guess that perhaps you're declaring something in a header file without "extern", so it's being treated as a definition in each file where that header is included.  These can be tough to track down, since the linker doesn't give you as much specific information as the compiler.

Comment: @Tim: That's what was happening with ChARS. I just placed it in a cpp file and extern'd it in the header file where all the code was moved to (made use of templates).

Comment: @Gman: Grab a LCD from http://crystalfontz.com. The CFA635 is a nice one. They're a lot of fun to program. These particular LCDs are packet based, which makes for some cool asynchronous fun. I've done this once in Python, but ran into limitations when it came to running graphic displays or controlling via USB. Hence this new project. It's based on the work I did in Python more less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's a `std` namespace within `LCDControl` that's hiding the global `std` namespace.  Try using `::std::map` instead of `std::map`.

I would say that either there's a `using namespace std` somewhere within the `LCDControl` namespace, or possibly there's an `#include` of a STL header that defines `std` within the `LCDControl` namespace.

e.g.:

```
namespace LCDControl
{
    #include <map>
}
```

Which would define all the symbols in `<map>` as part of `LCDControl::std`, which in turn would hide the global `std`, or at least any symbols defined in the inner namespace, I'm not sure.

When I tried this under VS2008, I got an error:

```
namespace testns
{
    int x = 1;
}

namespace hider
{
    namespace testns
    {
        int x = 2;
    }
}

int y = testns::x;
using namespace hider;
int z = testns::x;    // <= error C2872: 'testns' : ambiguous symbol
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what happened. Here I go 'a searching.

Comment: Yeah that's what it was. Curious that this didn't fix my initial issue. lol... CHAR is still defined multiple times according to the linker. Oh well, at least everything's inside a namespace now.

Answer (score 1):

The 'map' class lives in the std namespace, so you are going to have to qualify that somewhere.  How are you qualifying your map object?  You should have no problem doing this:

```
std::map<foo> myMap;
```

You can also do something like this if you do not want to explicitly qualify it every time, but also do not want to pollute your global namespace:

```
using std::map;
```

Comment: I'm qualifying it with std::map.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  Looks like your LCDControl namespace is polluting *your* global namespace.